# npm script fails with commands using process substitutions

Tags: node.js, bash, npm-scripts

Running the following on my standard OSX terminal works as expected:

```
$ diff <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2)
correct output here
```

But when I try to run it as an NPM script, it fails:

```
$ npm run diff
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `diff <(ls src) <(ls dist)'
```

When I change the NPM script to `"bash -c 'diff <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2)'"` it first outputs the desired result, then throws an error nevertheless (Exit status 1).

**Edit:** Those weird `<()` symbols are [process substitutions](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html#PROCESSSUBREF) by the way. Just learned about them.

Comment: The exit status might be the exit status of diff which is 1 if the files or your inputs are different so not necessarily an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To complement [Stefan Hegny's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40790482/45375) with background information:

From https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts:

> Scripts are run by passing the line as a script argument to `sh`.
>
> If the script exits with a code other than 0, then this will abort the process.

Specifically, the contents of the targeted `"scripts"` entry from your `package.json` file is passed to `sh -c` as an argument, so the command line equivalent of your command would be:

```
sh -c 'diff <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2)'
```

which will fail in the same way, because ***when Bash is invoked as `sh`*, by design it doesn't recognize [process substitutions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) (`<(...)`)**, because it runs in *POSIX compatibility mode*.

**Process substitutions are *not* part of POSIX**: they are a **Bash-specific** extension (also supported in `zsh` and `ksh`).

**For portability, you should only ever use [POSIX-mandated shell features](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) in your `"scripts"` entries - unless you explicitly invoke a specific shell** (as in Stefan's answer), either directly, or by invoking a script *file* whose shebang line specifies the shell to use.

Different shells act as `sh` on different platforms, and the only features you can rely on are those defined by POSIX.

Also **note how Stefan's answer uses `|| exit 0` at the end of the Bash command, so as to ensure that the overall command always reports exit code `0`**, to make sure that `npm` doesn't abort processing.

Comment: Kudos @mklement0 I actually had no idea about npm myself.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
"bash -c 'diff <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2) || exit 0'"
```